# Loop works/doesn't work, not sure why C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, loop-counter

I am having an issue with the `for` loop near the end of this code.

The loop is for a hangman game, and essentially the loop cycles through the `char` array with the secret word, and compares the user guess to each element in the `char` array. If it is found, it updates the output to show the letter and resets the counter to 0, or else if the counter equals the length of the secret word, that means the loop did **not** find the `char` and it should both add one to the display (for the hangman gallows) **and** place the incorrect guess in the wrong guess array.

The problem I am having here is that, for the most part the loop works as intended, but **occasionally** it will read a correct answer as being both correct **and** still places it within the wrong guess array, as well as increment the gallows display value.

It does this seemingly at random, and only when I play a second game. I thought it was an issue with the counter, but I have that reset to 0 both at the start of the `while` loop and reset to zero in the `for` loop **if** the correct answer is found.

So I don't know why it would read a correct answer as correct and still place it in the `wrongChoice` array, since the counter at that point should **not** be `wordLength - 1`. Here is the code:

```
while(!winner)
        {
            count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
                cout << userPrompt[i] << " ";
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            cout << "Wrong Guess: ";
            for(int i = 0; i < (secretWord.length() + 6); i++)
            {
                cout << userChoice[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n" << endl;
            displayGallows(display);

            if(display == 6)
            {
                cout << "Sorry, you lost!" << endl;
                break;
            }

            cout << "Enter a letter: ";
            cin >> userGuess;
            while(!cin)
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cin.clear();
                cin.sync();
                cout << "Error reading input character! Try Again!" << endl;
                cout << "Enter a letter: ";
                cin >> userGuess;
            }
            guessCount++;
            cin.ignore();
            for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
            {
                if(word[i] == tolower(userGuess))
                {
                    userPrompt[i] = tolower(userGuess);
                    count = 0;
                }
                else if(count == (wordLength - 1))
                {
                    display++;
                    userChoice[guessCount - 1] = toupper(userGuess);
                }
                count++;
            }
            winner = checkWin(word, userPrompt, display, secretWord);       
        }
        again = playAgain();
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for the debugger of your choice.

Comment: actually, as this is only my first semester in programming, our teacher didn't care to teach us how to use a debugger.....I have tried using Visual Basics debugger, but since I am a complete novice I had no luck trying to figure out that debugger on my own, and our teach says we learn how to use the debugger next semester :/ hard to figure all that stuff out on your own...... I go to these boards because it takes the teach at least 5 days to even return our email inquiries and by then the projects or assignments are already due

Comment: all that said, that is why I TRY to explain it the best I can when I post, including how I ASSUME the code should run, to show that I am trying to learn from these and not just get a quick answer to move on..... I really want to know/understand coding, not just get a quick A

Comment: Edit your post and clean up your code a bit... especially once you figure out what the answer is.  You may recover your down votes... (cout << "\n" << endl; is getting you 2 new lines??)

Comment: Lacking a debugger, your best bet is to cout the values of the variables that you think are going wrong.  That way you can narrow down where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A guess here, but is it only/always the first character that gives you the problem?

You use count as your detector if the userGuess was in the word[] somewhere, but if it was at the first character in word[] then count still increments the same way as if if the first character was wrong.  So at the end of your loop it **also** takes the branch of the incorrect choice.  Really what you wanted was to check after the loop ended... not every iteration of the loop!

try this:

```
        bool found = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word[i] == tolower(userGuess))
            {
                userPrompt[i] = tolower(userGuess);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if( !found )
        {
            display++;
            userChoice[guessCount - 1] = toupper(userGuess);
        }
```